# How to assign the return of a promise to a global variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

So... I have a function that returns a promise and I want to assign the value of a global variable to anything that this promise returns. How do I do that?

```
function a() {
  // Returns a promise
}
let b = a();
```

Now, b is a promise, but I want it to be whatever that promise returns instead.
I don't want to use .then because I want to use b in the if statement

```
function a() {
  // Returns a promise
}
let b = a();
if (b) {
  // Do stuff...
}
```

I know I could do it with

```
function a() {
  // Returns a promise
}
let b = a();
b.then(result => {
  if (result) {
    
  }
});
```

or even

```
function a() {
  // Returns a promise
}
a().then(result => {
  if (result) {
    
  }
});
```

but this just doesn't work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: `let b; a().then(result => b = result);` ... of course, you'll need to be careful HOW you access `b` since you won't know when it has the result ...

Comment: You could access `b` later with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`... That would work, eventually.. but until it works `b` will be undefined.

Comment: No, there's no secret method. You are basically asking if you can eat your pizza before it's delivered. You just need to learn to work with the async paradigm. If there was a reasonable way to do this, it would be in all the documentation and you wouldn't need to ask the question.

Comment: Here's the issue with asynchrony ... it's like a virus ... it infects any code dealing with it ... best solution is to learn to use asynchrony ... another solution ... `(async () => { let b = await a(); if (b) { ... }})()` - it looks synchronous, but it isn't (you don't need the IIFE if the code is already in an `async function` though)

Comment: Using `then` or `await` is the *only* way to access the promise result value. It will work for you like it does for everyone else.

Comment: @JaromandaX that's an IIAFE ;p

Comment: In a nutshell, you can't do what you want to do.  You can't immediately and synchronously get the value out of a promise and on the next line of code use that value in an `if` statement.  The value is NOT there initially.  It will only be available some indeterminate time in the future when the promise resolves and the ONLY way to know when the promise resolves is with `.then()` or `await`.  So, those are your two choices.  Use one or the other of those two options.  This will involve learning how to program asynchronous code in Javascript.  You will just need to learn that.

Comment: It is pointless to search for a "work-around".  One does not exist.  You need to learn how to program with an asynchronous result.  Using `await`, it's generally not that hard.  You do have to wrap your code in an `async` function (so you can use `await`), but it does let you write synchronous looking code flow for asynchronous operations.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone ... I don't know ... but in IIFE is an Immediately Invoked Function Expression ... `(function() { .... })()`